# Handlebars - display data from local storage

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I create simple crud app, that use localstorage for saving and retrieving objects. Now I want to replace ugly function, that concatenate JS + HTML, with Handlebars.js. I have a problem with displaying data from local storage in HTML template - do I have to write custom handlebars helper, or there is a simple solution?

There is my code
https://codepen.io/KamilNaja/pen/dWXYdd

HTML part

```
 <div id="output"></div>
  <script id="tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each itemData}}
      {{name}}
    {{/each}}
  </script>
```

JS - I wanna use render function

```
var app = {
    data: [],
    init: function () {
        this.cacheDom();
        this.bindEvents();
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        app.getFromLocalStorage();
        var itemData = app.items;
        var source = document.getElementById("tpl").innerHTML;
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = template(itemData);
    },
    cacheDom: function () {
        this.list = document.getElementById("list");
        this.addInput = document.getElementById("addInput");
        this.addBtn = document.getElementById("addBtn");
        this.document = $(document);
    },
    bindEvents: function () {
        this.addBtn.addEventListener("click", app.addItem);
        this.document.on("change", ".itemSelect", function (e) {
            if (this.value === "erase") {
                app.deleteItem(e);
            } else if (this.value === "edit") {
                app.editItem(e);
            }
        });
    },
    saveToLocalStorage: function () {
        localStorage.setItem("app.items", JSON.stringify(app.items));
    },
    getFromLocalStorage: function () {
        var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem("app.items");
        app.items = retrievedObject;
    },
    displayItem: function () {
        app.getFromLocalStorage();
        var data = "";
        //put into handlebars
        for (var i in this.items) {
            var optionValue =
                '<select class="itemSelect">' +
                '<option hidden value="unchosen">Options</option>' +
                '<option value="edit">Edit</option>' +
                '<option value="erase">Erase</option>' +
                '</select></li></span>';
            //nadaj kolejno id
            data += '<li class="listItem"><span id=' + i + ">" + app.items[i].name + optionValue;
        }
        app.list.innerHTML = data;
    },

    editItem: function (e) {
        app.getFromLocalStorage();
        var tableItemNumber = e.target.parentNode.id;
        var editItemValue = prompt("Edytuj");
        if (editItemValue.length === 0) {
            alert("Formularz jest pusty");
        }
        app.items[tableItemNumber].name = editItemValue;
        app.saveToLocalStorage();
        app.displayItem();
    },

};

app.init();
```

- Edit 
  I found the answer.
  HTML code gonna be the same. 
  Render function looks like this

  ```
  displayItem: function () {
        app.getFromLocalStorage();
        var data = "";

        var source = document.getElementById("tpl").innerHTML;
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        //below most important part 
        var html = template(app);
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;
  }
  ```

This code works well.

Comment: Check your app context replaced wherever needed.. in for Loop you have this.items or app.items ?!

Comment: app.items retrieves good data